# overriding devise routes works for sessions but not registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have the following code in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admin_users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'tap/registrations',
  sessions: 'tap/sessions',
  passwords: 'tap/passwords',
  confirmations: 'tap/confirmations'  
}
```

The code above creates the following routes:

```
        new_admin_user_session GET    /admin_users/sign_in(.:format)    tap/sessions#new
            admin_user_session POST   /admin_users/sign_in(.:format)    tap/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_user_session DELETE /admin_users/sign_out(.:format)   tap/sessions#destroy
           admin_user_password POST   /admin_users/password(.:format)   tap/passwords#create
       new_admin_user_password GET    /admin_users/password/new(.:format)  tap/passwords#new
      edit_admin_user_password GET    /admin_users/password/edit(.:format) tap/passwords#edit
                               PATCH  /admin_users/password(.:format)   tap/passwords#update
                               PUT    /admin_users/password(.:format)   tap/passwords#update
```

For some reason, the registrations and confirmations controller are not appearing in routes.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside model (admin_users.rb) have you added this line below, probably this [link can help you more](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for)

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
```

Comment: This was it - I added the line but somehow skipped :registerable.  Thanks!